# Enclose columns in CSV with ~

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file with delimiter as | , the values between the delimiter are not enclosed between quotes or any character. I am trying out a way to accept this file as an input and export a new CSV file with all the column to be enclosed in ^

Example:

Input:

```
1|Test|3
```

Output:

```
^1^|^Test^|^3^
```

Have tried below code but in vain:

```
get-content C:\ip.csv | foreach-object { $_ -replace '|' ,'^'} | set-content C:\op.csv
```

Comment: You should check out [Import-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176874.aspx) and [Export-Csv](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert text file to csv in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927080/how-to-convert-text-file-to-csv-in-powershell)

Comment: Thanks. That's true but Export-Csv by default enclosed double quote between values, I instead need the values to be enclosed between ^

Comment: Using `Import-Csv` at least you can get rid of the brittle `-replace`.

Comment: You could try adopting from [ConvertTo-Csv Output without quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647567/205233) (replacing quotes instead of removing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cont = get-content "D:\path\file.csv" 
$cont | % {
$info = "^" + $_.Split("|")[0] + "^" + $_.Split("|")[1] + "^" + $_.Split("|")[2] + "^"
$info  
}
```

Comment: This solution is limited to only 3 columns, I can have variable number of columns.

Comment: Yes =). Try this: $inform = Get-Content D:\csvs\comp.csv
$inform | % {
$info = $_.ToString().Replace("|","^") 
$info += "^"
$var = "^" + $info
$var | Out-file D:\csvs\test.csv -Append
}

Comment: Works! I tweaked a bit to retain | in output CSV file.

Comment: I am using below code:


` $inform = Get-Content E:\Test.csv.csv 
$inform | % { 
$info = $_.ToString().Replace("|","""|""") 
$info += """" 
$var = """" + $info 
$var | Out-file F:\Test1.csv -Append 
} `


Above code works for small file uptop 100 MB but if the file is huge (>200MB), the code takes huge time (more than 45 minutes) to convert, do we have more simpler approach...